# Deploying dependent jars into tomcat/lib in openshift

Tags: maven, tomcat, openshift

I'm developing a web-app that uses RestEasy,  I don't want to put the RestEasy jars in my web-app's WEB-INF/lib folderI want to put them in the openshift tomcat application lib directory where I'm deploying the war.  I'm under the impression I should use the pre or build hook capability. My questions are how do I get the dependencies I want and second how to I get them to my tomcat server?

Comment: I must ask.... why? Packaging dependencies within the WAR is how servlet containers are designed to work. Each application instance is run with it's own isolated class loader with no shared dependencies that could potentially break stuff in production. Even a process that inserts a jar into the WAR, prior to deployment, would be simpler to implement and more cross platform :-)

Comment: Because I want to develop WebApps that can be deployed to either JBoss EAP or Tomcat and I don't want to have to build them two separate ways, one with the dependencies (Tomcat 7: RestEasy not provided) and one without (JBoss EAP: RestEasy Provided).  Deployment is separate step in our build process and we will only be running one web-app per gear so it makes more sense for us to do configuration of the gear versus the app. @MarkO'Connor